# Gitective AndCommitFilter does not work when I add two AuthorFilter

Tags: java, jgit

I'm using the RevFilters in jGit with gitective. I was looking for list the commits of a particular user, and AuthorFilter works perfectly. However, now what I wanna do is to get the commits of one or more users.

When I execute the git log command on my repo I have

> joan@jomaora:~/testGit/testMockito$ git log commit
>   b5a49a83f052f632d78a09238056d4df8ebffb59 Author: Marc Czeck
>    Date:   Tue Aug 7 17:03:44 2012 +0200
>
> ```
> Modifying 1.
> ```
>
> commit 8d8dafd5242dbddf34a92ef39661b24167e25b0c Author: Joan
>   Ortega-Ardila  Date:   Tue Aug 7 17:01:37 2012
>   +0200
>
> ```
> Starting repo.
> ```

I have commits for this two users. My code works when I comment one of the AuthorFilter I added. Does AndCommitFilter does not accept to list this? This is my code:

```
FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(new File("/home/joan/testGit/testMockito/.git"))
    .readEnvironment()
    .findGitDir()
    .build();

PersonIdent p1 = new PersonIdent("Joan Ortega-Ardila", "jmortega@gmail.com");
PersonIdent p2 = new PersonIdent("Marc Czeck", "marc.czezk@gmail.com");

CommitListFilter list = new CommitListFilter();
AndCommitFilter filters = new AndCommitFilter();

filters.add(new AuthorFilter( p1 ));
filters.add(new AuthorFilter( p2 ));
filters.add(list);

CommitFinder finder = new CommitFinder(repository);
finder.setFilter(filters).find();

for(RevCommit rev : list.getCommits()){
    System.out.println(rev.getName());
    System.out.println(rev.getAuthorIdent().getName());
    System.out.println(rev.getShortMessage());
}
```

Thanks